# state is not updated in render. + Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have been stacked so long.
I have following component class that shows `<Input />` page and `<Confirm />` page.

I'm supposed to update by `state.mode` input/confirm.

When I fire dispatch in the `<Input/>` , it goes reducer and update `state.mode`.

```
class Sample extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            mode: 'input',
            params: []
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log('DEBGUG: ' + this.state.mode); //<-- Returns 'input', 'confirm' is expected.
        switch (this.state.mode) {
            case 'input':
                return (<InputForm />);
            case 'confirm':
                return (<ConfirmForm />);
            default:
                return (<InputForm />);
        }
    }
}
export default connect((state)=>state)(Sample);
```

```
    const initData = {
        mode: 'input'
    }
    export function sampleReducer(state = initData, action){
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'INPUT':
                return {mode: 'input'};
            case 'CONFIRM':
            return {mode: 'confirm'};
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
```

I expect to come to render and to show `<Confirm />` page.
However in the render, `this.state.mode` always return `input`.

What is wrong is it?

Comment: I’m not seeing you connect your component to your store using connect(), or any actions being dispatched by the component , or any mapping of store state to component props. How are you dispatching actions?

Comment: Actually yes I use `connect()` . I added sample code. I guess it might work.

Comment: So connect() mapStateToProps maps store state to props, can you clarify why you are evaluating component state instead of props that have the store values?

Comment: I’m new to React or even js. I’m very ambiguous how they are working. I’m going on.

Comment: Taking a step back, have you read through https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react ? It covers a lot of details regarding react + redux which has more complexities than just react. The issue here is redux.